# Flash AS3 Error: Line 48 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a beginner of the flash as3. I'm trying to create a game but in the beginning of my game project. A error comes. This is the error --> Line 48: 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
I don't know what is the problem, is anyone else know what is this problem if anybody know please tell me.
This is the code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        public function Main()
        {
            // variables and constants
            const NUMBER_OF_TILES:uint = 20;
            const TILES_PER_ROW:uint = 5;
            var tiles:Array=new Array();
            var tile:tile_movieclip;

            // end of variables and constants
            for (var i:uint=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TILES; i++)
            {
                tiles.push(Math.floor(i/2));
                trace("My tiles: "+tiles);
                // end of tiles creation loop

                // end of tiles creation loop add the following code:
                // shuffling loop
                var swap,tmp:uint;
                for (i=NUMBER_OF_TILES-1; i>0; i--)
                {
                    swap = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
                    tmp = tiles[i];
                    tiles[i] = tiles[swap];
                    tiles[swap] = tmp;
                    trace("My shuffled tiles: "+tiles);
                    // end of shuffling loop

                    //tile placing loop
                    for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_TILES; i++)
                    {
                        tile=new tile_movieclip();
                        addChild(tile);
                        tile.cardType = tiles[i];
                        tile.x=5+(tile.width+5)*(i%TILES_PER_ROW);
                        tile.y=5+(tile.height+5)*    (Math.floor(i/TILES_PER_ROW));
                        tile.gotoAndStop(NUMBER_OF_TILES/2+1);
                        tile.buttonMode = true;
                        tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTileClicked);
                        // end of tile placing loop
                     }  

                     private function onTileClicked(e:MouseEvent) {
                     trace("you picked a "+e.currentTarget.cardType);
                     e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(e.currentTarget.cardType+1);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not sure which one of your lines is :48 but as the code looks it must be inside the onTileClicked() methid. As normal cardType is not a property of e.currentTarget. Try to cast your e.currentTarget to your class used as tile.

Comment: ' private function onTileClicked(e:MouseEvent) {' this line is 48

Comment: 1. You cannot define a function inside a function. 2.you cannot use private/public... inside a function. To fix it take your private function onTileClicked(..) outside of the Main function

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu You can define a function inside of a function. See "nested functions" [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f57.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `private` function `onTileClicked` is inside your `Main` method. Access modifiers have to be used at the class level (the same level as your `Main` method), not inside other methods.

You should either remove the `private` modifier, or move the function to the class level. As it is, the function can't be accessed outside Main, so it doesn't need to be private.